# Why is $y''(x)=f''(u)\cdot [g'(x)]^2$ not correct?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Denote the **2-oder difference** of $y=f(x)$ as $\Delta^2 y$ , namely
\begin{align*} \Delta^2y&=\Delta(\Delta y)\\&=\Delta (f(x+\Delta x)-f(x))\\ &=f(x+\Delta x+\Delta x)-f(x+\Delta x)-(f(x+\Delta x)-f(x))\\ &=f(x+2\Delta x)-2f(x+\Delta x)+f(x).\\ \end{align*}
If $f(x)$ is **twice differentiable**, then we can prove that
\begin{align*} \lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{\Delta^2 y}{(\Delta x)^2}&=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{f(x+2\Delta x)-2f(x+\Delta x)+f(x)}{(\Delta x)^2}\\ &=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{2f'(x+2\Delta x)-2f'(x+\Delta x)}{2\Delta x}\\ &=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{f'(x+2\Delta x)-f'(x+\Delta x)}{\Delta x}\\
&=f''(x),\end{align*}
which shows that
$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{\Delta^2 y}{(\Delta x)^2}=\frac{{\rm d}^2 y}{({\rm d}x)^2}.$$
But, if we construct a composite function $y=y(x)$ with $y=f(u),u=g(x)$，where $f,g$ are also twice differentiable . Then
$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{\Delta^2 y}{\Delta x^2}=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\left(\frac{\Delta^2 y}{(\Delta u)^2}\cdot \frac{(\Delta u)^2}{(\Delta x)^2}\right),$$
which seems to imply
$$y''(x)=f''(u)\cdot [g'(x)]^2.$$
Of course, this is obviously **not** correct. But **where does the misitake occur?**

Answer (score 2):

The mistake lies in assuming $\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{\Delta^2 y}{(\Delta u)^2}=f''$ as $\Delta x\ne\Delta u$.

Comment: But $\Delta x \to 0$ implies $\Delta u \to 0$. We assume $f,g$ are twice differentiable

Comment: You can't switch limits like that.

Comment: @ Sorry，I can‘t grasp you very well. Could you elaborate it more clearly?

Comment: @mengdie1982, it is as TheSimpliFire says. In your last but one equation on the right hand side you treat $\Delta^2 y$ as though it were $f(x+2\Delta u)-2f(x+\Delta u)+f(x)$, but is is in fact $f(x+2\Delta x)-2f(x+\Delta x)+f(x)$; $\Delta u$ and $\Delta x$ are related in a complicated way,and you have to allow for that when you take the limits.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes,you're so clear.THX.

Answer (score 1):

I use the whell known fact 
$$
f(x+\lambda(x)\Delta x)=f(x)+\lambda(x) f'(x)\Delta x.\tag 1
$$ 
Then we have
$$
y=f(g(x))\Rightarrow\Delta y=\Delta f(g(x))=f\left(g\left(x+\Delta x\right)\right)-f(g(x))=
$$
$$
=f\left(g(x)+g'(x)\Delta x\right)-f(g(x))=f\left(g(x)\right)+g'(x)f'(g(x))\Delta x-f(g(x))=
$$
$$
=f'(g(x))g'(x)\Delta x
$$
As you observe $\Delta y$ is $f'(u)g'(x)\Delta x$ and Not $f'(u)\Delta x$ as you may expect.

So saying: For $y_1=f(x)$ we have
$$
\Delta y_1=f(x+\Delta x)-f(x),
$$
we mean that $\Delta y_1=f'(x)\Delta x$. To confuse two different $\Delta$'s ($\Delta x$ and $\Delta u$) is quite dangerous.